# How to pass parameters and the target of Input in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass parameters and the target of Input at the same time.

```
handleChange (e, a) => {
 this.setState({
  price: e.target.value
 });
 this.callback(e.target.value, a);
}
...
<input type = 'text' value = {this.state.price} onChange = {(e) => handleChange(a)} />
```

It didn't work as I wanted. I hope your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the first parameter to the `handleChange` function, try: `onChange = {(e) => handleChange(e, a)}`

Or you can do this:

```
handleChange = (a) => event => {
 this.setState({
  price: event.target.value
 });
 this.callback(event.target.value, a);
}
...
<input type = 'text' value = {this.state.price} onChange = {handleChange(a)} />
```